# OneHotEncoder : ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

df.LotFrontage = df.LotFrontage.fillna(value = 0)
categorical_mask = (df.dtypes == "object")
categorical_columns = df.columns[categorical_mask].tolist()
ohe = OneHotEncoder(categories = categorical_mask, sparse = False)
df_encoded = ohe.fit_transform(df)
print(df_encoded[:5, :])
```

ERROR:

[image: Error]

May I know whats wrong with my code?

This is a snippet of the data:

[[image: df.head]()][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4oBl.png)

Comment: Could you add the result of `df.head()` to your question?

Comment: From your code it looks like `categorical_mask` is a list of feature names but the docs say _"list : categories[i] holds the categories expected in the ith column."_ i.e. it should be a list of lists where each inner list contains the actual category levels (i.e. unique values) per column. You're getting a dimension mismatch because you're telling it each column has only 1 unique value in it.

Comment: If you are trying to apply the OHE only to categorical columns, I would recommend using a `ColumnTransformer` instead. Take a look at the example [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_tweedie_regression_insurance_claims.html#loading-datasets-basic-feature-extraction-and-target-definitions). And then don't specify the category levels in the OHE, let sklearn infer them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `categories` argument in the `OneHotEncoder` is not there to select which features to encode, for that you need a [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html). Try this:

```
df.LotFrontage = df.LotFrontage.fillna(value = 0)
categorical_features = df.select_dtypes("object").columns

column_trans = ColumnTransformer(
    [
        ("onehot_categorical", OneHotEncoder(), categorical_features),
    ],
    remainder="passthrough",  # or drop if you don't want the non-categoricals at all...
)
df_encoded = column_trans.fit_transform(df)
```

Note that according to [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), the categories argument is

> categories‘auto’ or a list of array-like, default=’auto’
>
> ```
> Categories (unique values) per feature:
>
>     ‘auto’ : Determine categories automatically from the training data.
>
>     list : categories[i] holds the categories expected in the ith column. The passed categories should not mix strings and numeric
> ```
>
> values within a single feature, and should be sorted in case of
>   numeric values.

So it should hold every possible category or level of each of the categorical features. You might use this is you know the full possible set of levels but suspect your training data might omit some. In your case, I don't think you;'ll need it so `'auto'`, i.e. the default, should be fine.